# Modificar clase de un _ngcontent-c0 en angular

Tags: css, bootstrap, angular

estoy haciendo una app con angular para ir aprendiendo y ahora mismo tengo el problema. He visto que me crea un div con clase container y dentro me pone todo el contenido de mi component que tengo en el html y claro a mi me interesaría poder modificarlo a fluid. Hay alguna manera de encontrar donde esta ese div? He visto que el _ngcontent-c0 es una encapsulación que hace angular pero no tengo claro si se puede modificar.

Adjunto una foto del codigo desde el navegador:

[image: Div with ngcontent]

Comment: Copia el nombre de la clase en tu archivo css custom o en el archivo de estilo de esa pantalla en caso que sea para esa especifica y al estilo modificado agregale !important esto al cargar los estilos pisa el otro. Saludos

Comment: No no, no quiero usar important ademas es una clase conatiner no la voy a modificar con css. Quiero saber donde esta el div para cambiar de container a container-fluid.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Edita tu pregunta y agrega tu código como texto en lugar de usar capturas ya que las preguntas así no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado ! Lo he encontrado en `src/app/app.component.html` por si a alguien mas le pasa.

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], si añades un ejemplo que que modificaste ayudaría mucho a hacer de mejor calidad tu aporte